# Can playground display errors as they happen?

Tags: xcode

In the playground REPL, am I missing an easy way to display errors as they happen?

It seems any error messages aren't visible by default. Xcode shows a red "!" disc next to the line, and that's it. I'd like to see the error message by default, and I'd like to be able to copy its text so I can use it for bug reports and SO searches.

The usual shortcuts for "Jump to next/previous issue" are disabled. Opening the issues tab with command-4 works, but it's empty. Apparently I have to mouse over and click on the tiny red disc to see any error message at all, and then it displays as text that can't be selected or copied.

Is there a way to reveal the error message by default? With a keyboard shortcut? Copy its text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `Editor > Show Issues` or `Editor > Issues > Show All Issues` will do that, and `ctrl-commmand-M` (or `⌃⌘ M`) toggles the setting.